# Browser Role does not shown in SSRS security

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2014

I want to create new role assignment in SSRS but the problem is I don't see `Browser Role` or some of built-in roles. Please help me to add built-in roles.

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you accessed this page through the link 'Site Settings', this will take you to System level roles only that's why you see Sys Admin and Sys user only.

If you need to assign a group to other built in roles, this should be done at folder lever, so you may need to use the link "Folder Settings" found SQL Server Reporting Services ribbon.
Depending on your security model you can do this at the root folder level or at specific folder level.